# Insert minimum values to vanish the array by removing k consecutive values

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I come across this problem in a random coding contest, I have already invested time to think about any solution but couldn't arrive to and also I have searched on the Internet to get some articles or any new Algorithmic concepts to solve this problem, but could not do so.

So I am asking your help, if you know any algorithm or come across any articles kindly share it below, it would be helpful for me, Yeah I am newbie in DSA, be nice in the comments:)

Let me give you the problem statement:

In this problem, we are given with a n - size array, and a value k, the objective of the problem is to find the minimum insert, you can insert any values to make it k consecutive, so you have to vanish the entire array with insertions. we can remove consecutive elements of size greater or equal to k, if we want to or we can do it later (basically for optimal removal). The test cases would give you a clear view about the objective.

the first line is space separated values n and k respectively, the second line is the array values, the third line is the expected output

```
test case 1

2 5
1 1
3

test case 2

5 3
2 2 3 2 2
2

test case 3

10 4
3 3 3 3 2 3 1 1 1 3
4
```

Explanation:

In the first testcase it is obvious to insert 3 values of 1 to remove 5 consecutive values so the answer is 3

In the second testcase, if we try to delete the 2 2 first we would end up spending like this 2 2 2 3 3 3 2 2 2, so the cost will be 4 , but we can insert 2 values of 3 in the middle after 3 to vanish 3 first and then 2 2 2 2 will automatically vanish without any insertion, so the expected cost is 2

In the third testcase also we will try to vanish the middle value 2 and 1 by inserting 3 values(2 2 1), so that 3 will automatically vanish.

Hope my explanation is clear, if you find any algorithm for solving this kind of tricky problem do comment below.

I tried greedy approach with stack but I know im the dumb to exist. so I gave up

Comment: It would be nice to look at **exact** problem description

Comment: Those examples don't line up with the narrative description of the algorithm. The description doesn't mention anything about inserts, but the examples all involve insertion.

Comment: @Welbog sorry I failed to say this in the question but my testcases are the one which i want to achieve

Comment: @MBo I Dont have the exact question but I just know the testcases and the constraints we have to follow to solve the question. Hope the test case and it's explanation makes sense

Comment: Having the exact problem description is absolutely essential. Details matter.